# Elasticsearch ingore special characters unless quoted

Tags: elasticsearch

I am making a search tool to query against text fields.

If the user searches for:

> 6ES7-820

Than I would like to return all documents containing:

- 6ES7820
- 6-ES7820
- 6ES7-820
- ...

In other words I would like to ignore special characters. I could achieve this by removing the special characters in my search analyzer and my indexing analyzer.

But when the user would search for the same term using quotation marks (or something else):

> "6ES7-820"

I want to only return the documents containing

- 6ES7-820

So then special characters should not be ignored. This means I can not remove these characters while indexing.

How could this search method be implemented in Elasticsearch, which analysers should I use?

Comment: I actually don't know, but did you try to specify a search and a different field analyzer? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/specify-analyzer.html#specify-index-field-analyzer

Comment: @dcolazin Yes a tried a different field analyzer. (I referred to this when saying indexing analyzer).

Comment: @Niya, what I would do is two fields, on of type `text` with an analyzer that strips the `-` and a `keyword` field with the full value. Query for both fields but put a boost on the field `keyword`